# Push view from navBar in app with tabBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

Im attempting to make an app that has both a `UITabBar` (as the root view controller) and also a `UINavigationBar` that are both consistently present throughout the app. My issue is that I'm trying to push a viewcontroller from the navBar but I can not find out how to do so. I understand that I need the `UINavigationBar` to be the `NavigationController`of the view controller I'm trying to push from but I cannot figure out how to do this.

In appDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let tabBar = window!.rootViewController
    let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: window!.frame.width, height: 64))

    let navBarItem = UINavigationItem(title: "Title")
    navBar.items = [navBarItem]

    tabBar?.view.addSubview(navBar)

    return true

}
```

In ViewController im trying to push new VC from

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let navBar = self.parentViewController?.view.subviews[2] as! UINavigationBar
    let navBarItem = navBar.items[0] as! UINavigationItem

    navBarItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "pushCreateVC:")
}

func pushCreateVC(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    println("push")

    let navBar = self.parentViewController?.view.subviews[2] as! UINavigationBar
    let navBarItem = navBar.items[0] as! UINavigationItem //left over code to reference the navBar from this method

    let createVC = CreateViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(createVC, animated: true) // This is where I want the navBar to push createVC so it still have the navBar at the top with a back button

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wanna do what you mention in the question, you should create a UITabbarController with UINavgationController(s) in it

```
//        First you need to create a nav controller with viewcontroller in it

var vc = UIViewController()
var navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

var tbController = UITabBarController()

//you can add more tab with more navControllers or viewcontrollers
tbController.setViewControllers([navController], animated: true)

//present the tbController as the main viewcontroller
```